# Print X for value of Array

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application, histogram

I'm trying to print "x" for the value within the array for example the integer 32 would print 32 x's but I'm not sure how to go about doing so.

Any help or pointers on what to do would be great have looked around but can't seem to find anything that helps me without over complicating it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Histogram
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string output = "";
            int[] x;
            x = new int[18];

            int[] y = { 32, 27, 64, 18, 95, 14, 90, 70, 60, 37, 17, 56, 99, 34, 75, 36, 12, 8, 100, 77 };

            const int ARRAY_SIZE = 18;
            int[] z;

            z = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];

            for (int i = 0; i < z.Length; i++)
                z[i] = 2 * i;              

            Console.WriteLine("Element\t \tValue\t \tHistogram\t\t\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
            {
                output += i + "\t\t" + y[i] + "\t\t" + y[i] + "\t\t" + "\n";                

            }
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To fill or append a string with n characters use [PadRight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_PadRight_System_Int32_System_Char_)

Comment: What is the usage of variables `x` and `z`, they have never used in your code?

Comment: Thanks for the link I'll take a look and see if I can work it out.

Comment: X is used to to print the element that the y value is within so Element 1 = 32 etc and as far as the z value I need to remove it actually @Nazim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is already built into String class. It has a constructor
to create a string of repeating chars for any length. No need for String Builder or any extra loops, that would be over complicated.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
      string output = "";
      const int ARRAY_SIZE = 18;
      int[] x = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
      int[] z = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
      int[] y = { 32, 27, 64, 18, 95, 14, 90, 70, 60, 37, 17, 56, 99, 34, 75, 36, 12, 8, 100, 77 };

      for (int i = 0; i < z.Length; i++)
            z[i] = 2 * i;

      Console.WriteLine("Element\t \tValue\t \tHistogram\t\t\n");
      for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
      {
           string bar = new string('X', y[i]);
           output += i + "\t\t" + y[i] + "\t\t" + bar + "\t\t" + "\n";
      }
      Console.WriteLine(output);
      Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Not sure you are following what I'm trying to do. For the values stored in the array I want to print a x for the value so for the value 32, 32 x's would be printed.

Comment: I see, I'll try implement it now and see how it goes.

Comment: Okay I edited it a second time, try that. I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I was not entirely sure if I was following what you wanted to do but this piece of code may be something like what you were doing with your loops.

Used StringBuilder because it "[doesn't create a new object in the memory but dynamically expands memory to accommodate the modified string](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-stringbuilder#:%7E:text=To%20solve%20this%20problem%2C%20C%23,to%20accommodate%20the%20modified%20string.)"

```
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string output = "";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("x");
            int[] y = { 32, 27, 64, 18, 95, 14, 90, 70, 60, 37, 17, 56, 99, 34, 75, 36, 12, 8, 100, 77 };
            //used to determine how many elements in the y array to go through
            const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
            int[] z;
            z = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
            
            for(int i=0; i< z.Length; i++){
                if(sb.Length != y[i])
                    sb.Clear();
                    for(int j=0; j < y[i]; j++)
                    sb.Append("x");
                    
            output += i + "\t\t" + y[i] + "\t\t" + sb + "\t\t" + "\n";
            //clear the string builder var for next set of x's
            sb.Clear();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would probably be to put the cout statement into 2 for loops. The first one for the length of the Array you want to print and the second one for the Number that is at that place.

As an example (`array` is the name of your array and `ARRAY_SIZE` is the length):

```
for (int x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE; x++) {
   for (int y = 0; y <= array[x]; y++) {
       output += x + " ";
   }
   output += "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hmm interesting, not to sure about this but I'll have a go and see how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `PadRight` method as @TaW suggested. I don't see any reason why you stored your result on the output variable, then printed it.

Please find my solution below(removed unnecessary codes) where I am printing immediately without a need to store anything in the memory:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const char paddingChar = 'X';
        const string tabs = "\t\t";
        int[] y = { 32, 27, 64, 18, 95, 14, 90, 70, 60, 37, 17, 56, 99, 34, 75, 36, 12, 8, 100, 77 };

        Console.WriteLine($"Element{tabs}Value{tabs}Histogram");
        for (int i = 0; i < y.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}{tabs}{y[i]}{tabs}{"".PadRight(y[i], paddingChar)}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```